# bar graph getting mixed up in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I am doing wrong I don't understand.

```
from numpy import datetime64
from pandas import Series
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dts
import datetime
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import mplcursors
timeSer = ['2017-01-01 11:43:07.050', '2017-01-01 11:43:23.000', '2017-01-01 11:42:45.000', '2017-01-01 11:43:55.000', '2017-01-01 11:48:38.000', '2017-01-01 11:57:47.000', '2017-01-01 12:13:16.000', '2017-01-01 12:17:03.000', '2017-01-01 12:18:15.000', '2017-01-01 12:18:27.000', '2017-01-01 12:18:34.000']
timeSer = pd.to_datetime(timeSer, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
lstBet = [1.0, 1.2, 1.0, 2.2, 3.0, 4.1, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0]
print("timeSer:",timeSer)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':lstBet, 'Date':timeSer})
# ax = plt.subplot(111)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.bar(timeSer, lstDeal, width=10)
# ax.bar(timeSer, lstDeal)
df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='value',ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dts.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
# df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='value',ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dts.DayLocator(interval=5))
# df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='value',ax=ax)
ax.xaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
# ax.set_xticklabels(timeSer, rotation=90)
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
plt.show()
```

I have updated the code. It's showing wrong value but at least x and x are visible in correct format. Issue is values are wrong.

Comment: You can fix the width of the bar with `ax.bar(x,y,width=VALUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out an answer and i am not sure that this is what you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dts
import datetime as dt

lstDatetm= ['2017-01-01 11:43:07.030', '2017-01-01 11:43:23.000', '2017-01-01 
            11:42:45.050', '2017-01-01 11:43:55.023', '2017-01-01 11:48:38.000', 
            '2017-01-01 11:57:47.521','2017-01-01 12:13:16.021', '2017-01-01 
            12:17:03.325','2017-01-01 12:18:15.005', '2017-01-01 12:18:27.000','2017- 
            01-01 12:18:34.000']
lstBet=[1.0, 1.2, 1.0, 2.2, 3.0, 4.1, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0]
newDatetm = [dt.datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for i in lstDatetm]


df = pd.DataFrame({'value':lstBet, 'Date':newDatetm})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dts.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dts.DayLocator(interval=5))
df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='value', ax=ax)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar Graph]

Happy coding, Thank you !

Comment: I ran your code. x axis is missing in it. you move the cursor. in bottom right you would see y changing but not the x. Sadly, this is not the solution.

Comment: I have updated the code. now x values are wrong but it's format is much closer it end result. See. Issue remains how to get correct values of time stamp on x axis.